# how to pass a post variable in mysql_fetch_assoc result

Tags: php, mysql

```
if($_POST)
    {
    $client = $_POST['client'];
    $insu1 = $_POST['insu1'];
    $insu2 = $_POST['insu2'];
    $date = date("dmY");

if($insu2 = 'alp' or $insu2='bppi' or $insu2='cpmp' or $insu2='carp' or $insu2='dsp' or $insu2='eep' or $insu2='earp' or $insu2='mbp')
{
//set @insu2 = $insu2;
$sql2 ="Select '$insu2' from tbl_engineering order by  timestamp( `timestamp` ) DESC limit 1 ";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

//$insu2_name ='';
var_dump($result2);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                {
                echo $insu2;
                var_dump($row);
                $insu2_name = $row[$_POST['insu2']];
                echo $insu2_name;


                }
```

From `$insu2_name = $row[$_POST['insu2']]`; I am getting column name, But I want the column Value. 
output of `$insu2_name = alp(column name of database)`

Guys help me

Comment: what is the value you are getting in var_dump($result2);

Comment: Try changing `$insu2_name = $row[$_POST['insu2']];` to `$insu2_name = $row['insu2'];`

Comment: @Angel value for $result2  = resource(7, mysql result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know that

```
select anyRandomSrting from table
```

will return anyRandomSrting if  **anyRandomSrting**  is not a column in the table.

In your case there will not be a column which name in $_POST['insu2'].

**Update**
Check this query once

```
"Select $insu2 from tbl_engineering order by  timestamp( `timestamp` ) DESC limit 1"
```

Please check that i have removed ' from $insu2

Comment: Its giving an error as "Notice: Undefined index: insu2"

Comment: I had tried this But still its giving me the column name

Comment: It there any collumn with name "$_POST['insu1'];" exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$insu2_name = $row[$_POST['insu2']];` to `$insu2_name = $row['insu2'];`

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the actual value for each of your fields in the table?